# Is pd.groupby a generator?

Tags: python, pandas

What is underneath the following loop?

```py
for name, group in df.groupby('some_col'):
    pass
```

Is it a generator or all groups are computed at once and stored in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `DataFrameGroupBy` object created by [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) is a generator, this is described in the documentation of [`DataFrameGroupBy.__iter__`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.__iter__.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.__iter__):

> Returns : Generator yielding sequence of (name, subsetted object) for
> each group

The grouper is generated in the beginning (i.e. the fact that rows a/b/c will form group X and x/y/z group Y), but the indexed groups themselves (i.e. the sub-dataframes) are generated on the fly.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'g': list('ABAB'),
                   'v': [7,8,9,10]})

gb = df.groupby('g')

# indices of the groups are pre-computed
print(gb.groups)

# slices are generated on the fly
for k,g in gb:
    print('---')
    print(f'Group: {k}')
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [0, 2], 'B': [1, 3]}
---
Group: A
   g  v
0  A  7
2  A  9
---
Group: B
   g   v
1  B   8
3  B  10
```